# How to find the earliest MMMYY from a date array?

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know how might I find the earliest MMMYY from an array of the following form (see column K).

Note: the date are not sorted in ascending order.

[image]

Code:

```
Sub outputfile()
'Capture the contract no. in ContractNo() array
Dim ContractNo() As String
'Capture the project title in ProjectTitle() array
Dim ProjectTitle() As String
'Capture the contract start in ContractStart() array
Dim ContractStart() As Date
'Capture the contract end in ContractEnd() array
Dim ContractEnd() As Date

'Capture ASPQ Cement in ASPQC() array
Dim ASPQC() As Double
'Capture ASP Sand in ASPQS() array
Dim ASPQS() As Double
'Capture ASP Aggregate in ASPQA() array
Dim ASPQA() As Double

i = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value)
i = i + 1
Loop

ReDim ContractNo(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ProjectTitle(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ContractStart(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ContractEnd(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ASPQC(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ASPQS(1 To i - 2)
ReDim ASPQA(1 To i - 2)

For i = 1 To UBound(ContractNo, 1)
ContractNo(i) = Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
ProjectTitle(i) = Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
ContractStart(i) = Cells(i + 1, 11).Value
ContractEnd(i) = Cells(i + 1, 12).Value
ASPQC(i) = Cells(i + 1, 14).Value
ASPQS(i) = Cells(i + 1, 15).Value
ASPQA(i) = Cells(i + 1, 16).Value
Next i

End sub
```

Comment: I must admin I don't know VBA, but isn't there like a "min()" method or so ?

Comment: I thought of using min() function, but would like to know whether there is a better method out there. :)

Comment: Well, if there's a working built-in function, why would you even think you can do better ? Now I'm not saying this is working, but you seem to agree it is...

Comment: It's actually not working.

Comment: why not `=TEXT(MIN(K:K), "MMMYY")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best is a built in formula in a cell.

```
=TEXT(MIN(K:K), "MMMYY")
```